# closed subspace $Y$ implies existence of non-zero linear functional $g$ such that $Y \subset \ker(g)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I am working on an exercise and I am not sure if I am on the right track, so if anyone could give some hints I would be grateful. The exercise is

If $Y$ is a proper closed subspace of $X$, prove that there is a non-zero linear functional $g \in X'$ such that $Y \subset \ker(g)$.

What I have done so far:

I am trying to use the following theorem to prove this statement:

Assume that there is an $x \in X$ such that
\begin{align*}
\delta = \inf_{w \in W} \|x -  w\| >0,
\end{align*}
then there exists $f \in X'$ such that $\| f \| = 1$, $f(x) = \delta$ and $f(w) = 0$ for all $w \in W$.

It is clear to me that since $Y$ is a proper subspace and is closed,  all $x \in X \setminus Y$ have $\| x - y \| >0$, but I cannot find a specific $x \in X$ that demonstrably  has this property...

Any assistance would be very welcome. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick any $x \in X \setminus Y$. Suppose
$$0 = \inf_{y \in Y} \| x - y\|.$$
From here, you get a contradiction to the closedness of $Y$.

Comment: That indeed proves it. How stupid of me not to see that... Thanks!