# A question regarding Hahn Banach theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-writing, hahn-banach-theorem

> Let $Y=\{(a_n)\in l^2 : a_2=2a_1 , a_4=4a_3\}$.
> Is there exist a functional $f \neq 0 \in X^*$ such that $f(Y)={0}$.

I know that it can be done using the Hahn-Banach corollary, which says, if $X$ is a normed space, $Y\subset X$ a closed sub-space, and $x \in X\setminus Y$, then there is a functional $f \in X^*$ such that $\|f\|=1$ ,  $f$ restricted to $Y$ equals $0$ ,and $f(x)=d=\inf_{y\in Y} \|x-y\|$.

Clearly $l_2$ is a normed space. And we can find a sequence $a_n\in l^2\setminus Y$ with $\|a_n\|_2=1$.
In order to show that $Y$ is closed in $X$ I have to take a sequence $b_n\in Y$ such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n =x$ and show that $x\in X$ but is not that obvious according to $Y$'s definition?

Any support would be kindly welcomed.

Comment: It looks like you're mixing a few notations and a few corollaries of the Hahn-Banach theorem (how is $\|f(x)\|=1$ and $f(x)=d$?), can you please review this and make sure everything is as intended?

Comment: Yes, you are right, i edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than resort to using the Hahn-Banach theorem to solve this problem, perhaps consider a constructive approach:

Define $f:l_2\to\mathbb C$ by $f(a_n)=-2a_1+a_2$.  This map is certainly linear, $f\neq 0$, $f(Y)=0$, and by Hölder's inequality, we have
$$|f(a_n)|=|-2a_1+a_2|\leq((-2)^2+1^2)^{1/2}\|(a_n)\|_2=\sqrt 5\ \|(a_n)\|_2,$$
So $f\in(l_2)^*$.

Comment: Thanks @Aweygan so you actually chose to define f with $a_1$ & $a_2$, you could also ddfine it with $a_3$ and $a_4$  ..right?  How can I see that $f \neq 0$ ?

Comment: To answer your first question, for any nonzero pair $(b_1,b_2)\in\mathbb F^2$ (where $\mathbb F=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$) you could instead define $$f(a_n)=b_1(-2a_1+a_2)+b_1(-4a_3+a_4).$$
For your second, if $a_1=1$ and $a_n=0$ for $n\geq 2$, then $(a_n)\in l_2$ and $f(a_n)=-2\neq 0$, so $f\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks @Aweygan last thing I am not getting the inequality where you used Holder,  why is this true (since Holder works for $L^p$ spces)..

Answer (score 3):

Since norm-convergence in $\ell^2$ implies pointwise convergence (each entry of the sequence converges), it follows that $Y$ is a closed subspace of $\ell^2$. Moreover, it is easy to see that $\ell^2 \neq Y.$ Then invoke the following corollary of the Hahn-Banach (separation) theorem:

> Let $V$ be a normed space and $Y$ be a proper closed subspace of $V$. Then there exists a non-zero continuous functional $\tau \in V^*$  with $\tau(Y) = \{0\}$.

Comment: Hi @MathQED is there a proof to this corollary?

Comment: Hi @Maths1999_ You can have a look here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611524/closed-subspace-y-implies-existence-of-non-zero-linear-functional-g-such-tha

Comment: I am not getting it  unfortunatly! @MathQED

Comment: I could not open the link..

Comment: Sorry, my bad: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221882/why-is-this-a-corollary-from-hahn-banch?rq=1